# How to remove MySQL tables prefix in InnoDB database with constraints

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, innodb

I have MySQL database about 5GB size and about 200 tables in it. All tables have prefix which I'd like to remove and I found some ideas for that.

The problem is that this database has referential integrity checking by using CONSTRAINT...FOREIGN KEY.

How to remove prefix from tables, including change in constraints, without manual modification or removing constraints?

Comment: The manual for rename table says "Foreign keys that point to the renamed table are not automatically updated. In such cases, **you must drop and re-create the foreign keys in order for them to function properly.**"

Comment: Doesn't `rename table` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to drop and recreate the foreign keys according to the mysql documentation on [rename table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html):

> Foreign keys that point to the renamed table are not automatically
>   updated. In such cases, you must drop and re-create the foreign keys
>   in order for them to function properly.

Comment: I found an idea to export whole database to sql script and do string replace on it, then imported it. This is not very convincing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tables in `information_schema` (mostly `TABLES` and `COLUMNS`) to construct the code you need.  Perhaps 3 scripts would be wise:

1. `SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ' ... ) FROM ...`
2. `SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', ...`
3. `SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' ADD FOREIGN KEY ' ... ) FROM ...`

Then manually copy and paste the 3 scripts into the mysql commandline tool.

As for removing the prefix, look at the string functions `MID`, `LOCATE`, `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, etc., to see what would be useful.